# How to fix 'MemoryError' while fitting keras model with fit_generator?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform

I'm training a unet on a google cloud tensorflow vm instance. When I run fit_generator, I get a MemoryError.

When I run the same code locally on tensorflow (cpu version), this does not happen. I have tried increasing the RAM to 13GB on the VM instance (larger than my local machine).

```py
model = unet()
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('unet_membrane.hdf5', monitor='loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
model.fit_generator(myGene,steps_per_epoch=300,epochs=1,callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
```

I expect the model to train, but instead I get a MemoryError with the following Traceback

```
Epoch 1/1
Found 30 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 30 images belonging to 1 classes.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    model.fit_generator(myGene,steps_per_epoch=300,epochs=1,callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1418, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 181, in fit_generator
    generator_output = next(output_generator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 709, in get
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 685, in get
    inputs = self.queue.get(block=True).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
MemoryError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like your machine has run out of memory and can't train while storing all the arrays at the same time. Try to optimize your code to maybe save arrays of data, then loading them when needed so you don't have to store them in your RAM.